# different fieldsets and admin form depending of `request`

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

How i can define need `admin-form` and `admin-fieldsets` in depending of `request` object?
For example:

I have some model:

```
# models.py
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.TextField(...)
    params = models.SomeField(...)
```

And i have field in `user.profile` as `role` (`administrator`, `owner`, `seller`)
I want in depending of `user.profile.role` to get in admin interface defferent fieldsets, for example:

```py
# admin.py
class ShopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def custom_get_fieldset_and_form_method(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.profile.role == 'administator':
            self.fieldsets = self.get_default_fieldset_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.user.profile.role == 'owner':
            self.fieldsets = [
            (
                'Owner Panel', {'fields': ('name', 'description')},
            ),
            (
                'Hidden fields', {'classes':('collapse',),'fields': (`params`,)},
            )]
        else:
            # in other, i want to hide `params` field from form
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the [get_fieldsets()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets) method of your model admin, which receives the `request` object as one of its arguments:

```
# NOT TESTED
class ShopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        profile = YourProfileModel.objects.get(user=request.user)

        if profile.role == 'administrator':
            fieldsets = self.get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        elif profile == 'owner':
            fieldsets = (
                ('Owner Panel', {'fields': ('name', 'description',)}),
                ('Hidden fields', {'classes':('collapse',),'fields': ('params',)})
            )
        else:
            # additional fieldsets

        return fieldsets
```

If you're wanting to include/exclude specific fields based on the user profile, you need to override the model admin's [get_form()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method, which will give you access to the request.